# Use custom JavaScript code in a Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to insert JavaScript code in a Vue.js router app. I need to load data from the CMS the app is served from. In order to get the data from the CMS I have to use a JavaScript library from the CMS which is not made for Vue and is not exporting it's class/functions like modern JS. So I import the JS library from in the index.html by a script tag. This works as intended.

But now I have to use the class from this CMS JavaScript library.
Before writing this as a Vue-Router app I just have used Vue for templating purposes.
So I had some code packed in the window.onload event handler.
I have to create an instance for the CMS data access class.
But this leads to a build error (using vue-cli build). Since there
are no understandable error messages from the build process
I have to use trial and error. Even simple variable assignments like `var a = 1` seem not to be allowed.
A console.log('something') works. But nothing else seemes to be allowed (except defining the onload-event handler)

I have added this code in a `<script>` Tag inside App.vue (which was created by vue-cli create)

```
window.onload = function() {
    
    try {
        // Instantiate class obj for CMS data access
        cmsDataAccessObj = new CMSAccessData();
        waitForPlayerData = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

After testing the different solutions from the answers I got aware that using non-instance variables seems to cause the build errors.

This gives an error:

```
        waitForPlayerData = true;
```

This works:

```
        this.waitForPlayerData = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend using `window.load` to run your code. There are more native approaches to do this in Vue.js.

What you should do in the case you want to run it in the main component of the app before it's been loaded is to put the code inside the `beforeCreate` lifecycle hook of the main component.

```js
...
beforeCreate () {
  this.cmsDataLoader()
},
methods: {
  cmsDataLoader () {
    try {
        // Instantiate class obj for CMS data access
        cmsDataAccessObj = new CMSAccessData();
        waitForPlayerData = true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
  }
}
...
```

This will run the code everytime a component is created **before** the creation. You could also use the `created` lifecycle hook if you want to run it **after** the creation of the component.

Check the following link for more information about [lifecycle hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Comment: I'm not sure if it's good to have the code run for every component. I just need it run on the start of the whole app and access the object/instance in every component. The CMSAccessData is designed to init the whole CMS communication. Additionally the real data exchange is done by another CMS-custom event-handler to which the data is passed.

Comment: It won't run in every component, only in the main App.vue, which I guess is the one that has the router view.

Comment: I have added this test-code to my App.vue main component:
`<script>
export default {
  beforeCreate() {
    this.cmsDataLoader();
  },
  methods: {
    cmsDataLoader() {
              waitForPlayerData = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>`

It also give me a build error

Comment: Concerning the place where to add the code the hook seems to be a good place, also recommended by the Vue documentation.

Comment: What build error are you getting? I think you would have to import the `CMSAccessData` class to be able to instantiate it.

Comment: Did only see some node errors, but cannot get them back. I found the solution by only using instance variables with `this`. Now everything works. I have placed it in the main.js file in the Vue instance creation. The only problem seems to be that a method defined in the `methods` section cannot be used as an event handler (it's `undefined`).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to place JavaScript in Vue.js App is `mounted` function, it is called when the component is loaded:

```js
export default {
    name: "component_name",
    mounted() {
        let array = document.querySelectorAll('.list_item');
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need window.onload, you can just put whatever you want there. I'm not entirely certain when precisely in the lifecycle it renders and maybe someone can hop in and let us know but it for sure renders when page starts. (though it makes sense that it does before the lifecycle hooks even start and that it'll solve your needs)
2. Better & easier solution if you want to load it before Vue loads is to add it to the main.js file. You have full control there and you can load it before Vue initializes.

No need for window.onload there either, just put it before or import a JS file before you initialize Vue, because it's going to be initialized by order.

Comment: If I put something in the main.js the build fails. Especially if I make just some variable initializations. Only console.log statements work there. It even makes no difference if I put in inside the onload-event-handler or just outside any function.